# Randomly join tables and return columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE DimEmployee(EmployeeID INT)
CREATE TABLE DimDepartment(DepartmentID INT)
CREATE TABLE DimDocteur(PositionID INT)

INSERT INTO DimEmployee(EmployeeID) VALUES (1),(2),(3)
INSERT INTO DimDepartment(DepartmentID) VALUES (1),(5),(6)
INSERT INTO DimPosition(PositionID) VALUES (7),(8),(9)
```

I want to randomly join the 3 tables and get output like below : (example)

First execute:

```
EmployeeID DepartmentID PositionID RandomDate
1          4            7          2020-07-24 00:00:00.000
2          5            9          2020-11-25 00:00:00.000
```

Second execute:

```
EmployeeID DepartmentID PositionID RandomDate
1          4            7          2020-05-04 00:00:00.000  
2          5            9          2020-10-30 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: "Randomly join" is not a SQL operation.  Please provide more information on what **you** mean by that expression.

Comment: Do you need *every* possible combination, or do you want each patient to take one random maladie and docteur

Comment: USe a CTE to give each table an `ROW_NUMBER` value with an arbitrary value, and `JOIN` on that? It won't be random, but it's still arbitrary.

Comment: @Charlieface I want the random option

Answer (score 1):

If you want a random join :

```
SELECT DP.EmployeeID, Q.Department INTO #T1
FROM DimEmployee AS DP

CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 Dd.DepartmentID FROM DimDepartment AS DD
ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS Q


SELECT * 
INTO #T2
FROM #T1 AS T
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 DP.PositionID FROM DimPosition AS DP
ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS Q
```

Or if you want all possibilities :

```
SELECT 
    a.EmployeeID,  b.DepartmentID, c.PositionID
FROM 
    DimEmployee AS a 
  CROSS JOIN 
    DimDepartment AS b
  CROSS JOIN 
    DimPosition AS c
```

Comment: The OP wants the random option, but it is useful to retain both and specify which is random and which is all... like you have done here.

Comment: The way you have done the random option can result in the same row being joined multiple times, which may not be what OP wants

Answer (score 0):

You need to row-number each table and join on row-number:

```sql
CREATE TABLE DimEmployee(EmployeeID INT)
CREATE TABLE DimDepartment(DepartmentID INT)
CREATE TABLE DimDocteur(PositionID INT)

SELECT
    emp.EmployeeID,
    dep.DepartmentID,
    doc.PositionID,
    DATEADD(day, (ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 65530), 0) RandomDate
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM DimEmployee
) emp
JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM DimDepartment
) dep ON dep.rn = emp.rn
JOIN (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) rn
    FROM DimDocteur
) doc ON doc.rn = emp.rn
```

You can also change the `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY NEWID()` to get a more random ordering.